# Unable to install .apk from app

Tags: android, download, installation, apk

I have an app hosted on SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pokedroid/). I decided to add a button to download the newest version of the app straight from the CVS server. The .apk downloads fine, but when I try to install it, the package installer gives a "cannot parse package" error. The code I'm using:

```
    private class DownloadAndInstall extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... derp)
    {
        String ur=derp[0];
        String fileName=derp[1];
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(ur);
            URLConnection ucon = null;
            ucon = url.openConnection();

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            int current = 0;
            int updateCount=0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
                if(updateCount==256)
                {
                    publishProgress(baf.length());
                    updateCount=0;
                }
                baf.append((byte) current);
                updateCount++;
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = PokeDroid.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("pokedroid", e.toString());
        }

        MessageDigest digest = null;
        try {
            digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("pokedroid", e.toString());
        }
        digest.update(baf.toByteArray());
        byte[] h = digest.digest();

        if(baf.length()==0)
            return null;
        String[] fileList=fileList();
        boolean exists=false;
        for(String i:fileList)
            if(i.equals("updatehash.md5"))
                exists=true;

        String newHash=new String(h);
        Log.e("pokedroid", "new="+newHash);

        if(exists)
        {
            try
            {
                String oldHash=loadObject("updatehash.md5");
                Log.e("pokedroid", "old="+oldHash);
                if(oldHash.equals(newHash))
                    return false;
                else
                    saveObject(newHash, "updatehash.md5");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("pokedroid",e.toString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try {
                saveObject(newHash, "updatehash.md5");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("pokedroid",e.toString());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...integers)
    {
        p.setMessage("Downloading update...\n"+integers[0]/1000+"kb downloaded so far.");
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b)
    {
        if(b==null)
        {
            noConnection.show();
            deleteFile("PokeDroid.apk");
            p.dismiss();
            return;
        }
        if(!b)
            noNewUpdate.show();
        else
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///data/data/com.games.pokedroid/files/PokeDroid.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);
            deleteFile("PokeDroid.apk");
        }
        p.dismiss();
    }

    public void saveObject(String obj, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(obj);
        out.close();
        fos.close();
    }

    public String loadObject(String filename) throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        FileInputStream fis=openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        String out=(String) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fis.close();
        return out;
    }
}
```

This is a subclass in my Activity, of course. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should make sure that you are creating and attempting to ACTION_VIEW the same file.  And hard coding an absolute path into your application's private storage strikes me as making unwarranted assumptions. If you are going to make it world readable anyway, why not just put in on the sdcard? (well, okay, yes, that makes it no only readable but easier to find - but this may help you sort out the problem)

Comment: Hi notverycreative,
I want to do the same thing which you have done but after startActivityForResult(intent); its giving me error that "There was problem parsing the package". Can you please help me in this?

Comment: There may be an issue with the package (e.g. incorrectly signed, corrupted when transferred, etc.). If that's not it, I honestly don't know; I haven't done anything more with Android since I posted this question a year or so ago. You may want to ask a new question instead. Sorry if I'm not very helpful :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see one issue in your code:

```
 startActivity(intent);
 deleteFile("PokeDroid.apk");
```

This code sends intent and then deletes the file. Note that `startActivity` is asynchronous function. I.e. it sends the request, but does not wait for completion of that request. So when the intent is actually received by Application Installer Activity (let's call it that way ) your `.apk` file has already been deleted by you.

**How to fix**:

You need to replace those two lines of code with:

```
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

And then in `onActivityResult` function:

```
deleteFile("PokeDroid.apk");
```

Comment: Oh, wow, I can't believe I missed that. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked that your mobile is configured to accept 3rd party apps?

is the apk signed?

Comment: This is probably the issue.  An unsigned version will never overwrite a signed one.  And then of course also the 3rd party thing.  ;)